# Is it possible to find out the id of the element mouse is curently pointing at (not clicking) with only javascript, no libraries?

Tags: javascript

I have few separate elements in my html page right next to each other.

I want to show certain content while mouse is on one of those elements, and hide it when mouse moves away from them.

If I just use mouseon/mouseout events, I get some flickering on content i want to show when i move the mouse between correct elements.

For solution I figured i could create an aray of correct element ID's and then check if mouse is pointing at any of array's elements. But can't find a way to get element's id without clicking it.

So is it possible to get the id of the element mouse is curently hovering or pointing at without jquery or other libraries?

HTML part:

```
<div id="navigationBarContainer">
    <ul id="navigationBarList">
      <li>Naujienos</li>
      <li id="dropDownBarControl">Veikla
        <ul id="dropDownBar" class="hideList">
          <li id="preschool" class="hide">Pradine</li>
          <li id="middleschool" class="hide">Pagrindine</li>
          <li id="highschool" class="hide">Abiturientai</li>
          <li id="grownups" class="hide">Suauge</li>
          <li id="conferences" class="hide">Konferencijos</li>
          <li id="other" class="hide">Teminiai</li>
        </ul><!--end of dropDownBar-->
      </li>
      <li>Kainorastis</li>
      <li>Registracija
        <ul>
          <li id="forStudents" class="hide">Mokiniams</li>
          <li id="forGrownups" class="hide">Suaugusiems</li>
        </ul><!--end of dropDownBar-->
      </li>
      <li>Kontaktai</li>
    </ul><!--end of navigationBarList-->
  </div><!--end of navigationBarContainer-->
```

and Javascript:

```
function showItem(name){//make item visable    
  document.getElementById(name).classList.remove("hide");   
}
function hideItem(name){//make item hidden
  document.getElementById(name).classList.add("hide");
}
document.getElementById('dropDownBarControl').addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  document.getElementById('dropDownBar').classList.replace("hideList", "showList");
  var links = ["preschool","middleschool","highschool","grownups","conferences","other"];
  var time = 0;
  links.forEach(function(element){
    time = time + 20;
    setTimeout(function(){
      showItem(element);
    }, time);
  });
});

document.getElementById('dropDownBar').addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  document.getElementById('dropDownBar').classList.replace("showList", "hideList");
  var links = ["other","conferences","grownups","highschool","middleschool","preschool"];
  var time = 0;
  links.forEach(function(element){
    time = time + 20;
    setTimeout(function(){
      hideItem(element);
    }, time);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets.

Comment: I don't really have a code for this, because i don't even know if that can be done. Been searching for almost an hour now, and few solutions that i found all used jquerry. Haven't found anything atleast close with just javascript.

Comment: You must have had some code to create the flickering described. Show us that code. We recognize it doesn't work but that is the whole point of this site...to help people fix code that doesn't work as expected

Comment: Added the code to question, sorry if it is messy and hard to read. What it is meant to do is to extend dropDownBar and show all <li's> inside of it when dropDownBarControl is moused over, and hide it when mouse moves to something that does not belong to the dropDownBarControl. But when i mouse over between <li's> the dropDownBar stays open as it shoud, but <li's> themselves flicker around like crazy. How can i solve this?

Comment: Try looking here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint

Answer (score 0):

Listens to mouse move and tracks when the underlying element changes.

uses `document.elementAtPoint(x,y);`

```js
let element = undefined;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  let x = event.pageX;
  let y = event.pageY;
  
  let newElement = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
  if(!element || element !== newElement) {
    element = newElement;
    console.log(element.id||element);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<div id="navigationBarContainer">
    <ul id="navigationBarList">
      <li>Naujienos</li>
      <li id="dropDownBarControl">Veikla
        <ul id="dropDownBar" class="hideList">
          <li id="preschool" class="hide">Pradine</li>
          <li id="middleschool" class="hide">Pagrindine</li>
          <li id="highschool" class="hide">Abiturientai</li>
          <li id="grownups" class="hide">Suauge</li>
          <li id="conferences" class="hide">Konferencijos</li>
          <li id="other" class="hide">Teminiai</li>
        </ul><!--end of dropDownBar-->
      </li>
      <li>Kainorastis</li>
      <li>Registracija
        <ul>
          <li id="forStudents" class="hide">Mokiniams</li>
          <li id="forGrownups" class="hide">Suaugusiems</li>
        </ul><!--end of dropDownBar-->
      </li>
      <li>Kontaktai</li>
    </ul><!--end of navigationBarList-->
  </div><!--end of navigationBarContainer-->
```